# Setting background color for Spinner Item on selection

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html) control in my code. I want the item to get highlighted (i.e., background color changed for that item) on selection. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 9):

create a xml: for ex:mybg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/anyColor" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

and in your activity xml

do

```
  <Spinner...............
  android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
  android:background="@drawable/mybg"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Create custom View layout (e.g. from TextView)
2. Create Selector and set it as a background of that view
3. Set Spinner with custom view

Selector: custom_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@color/light_grey" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/light_grey" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/light_grey" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/light_grey"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Custom View layout: my_simple_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:lines="1"
android:padding="5dip"
android:background="@drawable/custom_selector"/>
```

Initialise Spinner:

```
String[] items = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_simple_item, items);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: When scroll using wheel of my mouse no any effect. Items should be light_grey but instead they are orange(default color for android 2.2)
see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737811/spinner-does-not-apply-dropdownselector-attribute