# Spinner does not apply dropDownSelector attribute

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I'm using spinner and want to add spinner - to change behavior depends of states(focused, pressed)

sample project is here https://github.com/vovs/spinner_issue

My code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:dropDownSelector="@drawable/spinner_state" />
```

**spinner_state.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@color/black" />
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/red" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/red" />
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

So, if I run app in emulator Android 4.0.2 API 14 and try to select some item or scroll using wheel of my mouse no any effect, that I set in selector(when press or scrolling - items should be red, but it is blue - default for ICS color).

For Android 2.2 API 8 when press or scroll using wheel(in this case state is focused) color is yellow[orange](default color for Android 2.2)

How to enable selector for spinner?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

also an official bug...
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24922

what helps:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Theme.MyListView</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MyListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/orange_list</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

good luck!

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/lighter_gray_no_transparent" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/lighter_gray_no_transparent" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/lighter_gray_no_transparent" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>

<color name="lighter_gray_no_transparent">#FFDDDDDD</color>
```

set backgroud selector for your item view, that's all. Work for me. ***The color alpha value should be FF, or it will show orange background***, left one color value is **#FFDDDDDD**, the right one is **#55DDDDDD**

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There may be other ways but here's what I understand from using one of the [Generators](http://android-holo-colors.com/).

Declare your own style for the spinner in your `res/values/styles.xml` pointing to your drawable.

```
<style name="myCustomSpinner" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_state</item>
</style>
```

Create `res/values/themes.xml` and declare your own theme that inherits from the current theme. Within this theme, add an item for each attribute you're modifying and point it to your custom style from the last step. I think this could go in the styles file if you wanted, but since the generator separates them I follow suit.

```
<style name="myCustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:dropDownSpinnerStyle">@style/myCustomSpinner</item>
</style>
```

In your `AndroidManifest`, add `android:theme="@style/myCustomTheme"` to the opening `application` tag.

Your values for `parent` will depend on how the project is setup and I think this will style of the spinners in your project and not just one. Try it out and let me know what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution similar to what [es0329](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18193015/18597115) gave:

```
    <style name="Base.Theme.SpinnerDemo" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/My.Theme.Spinner</item>
    </style>

    <style name="My.Theme.Spinner" parent= "android:Widget.ListView">
        <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/spinner_selector</item>
    </style>
```

And here are my explanations on how and why this works.

## Why didn't `android:dropDownSelector` work ?

It all comes down to what happen when we click on the Spinner. Once clicked, it will go through a process to create a **DropDownListView**.

During its creation, it will use the build-in attribute `R.attr.dropDownListViewStyle` to create **AbsListView**.

Then, the AbsListView will extract the drawable from `R.styleable.AbsListView_listSelector` attr, which will become the selector:

```java
final Drawable selector = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.AbsListView_listSelector);
if (selector != null) {
    setSelector(selector);
}
```

As a result, the `android:dropDownSelector` that we gave it to Spinner does not have any effects on the AbsListView that is created for popup.

That's why in order to actually set the selector, we need to change the `android:listSelector` from the Theme.

## Why use `android:Widget.ListView` as the parent of the theme ?

If we look into our application theme, we should find something like this :

```
<style name="{THEME_NAME}" parent="{PARENT_THEME}">
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">?android:attr/dropDownListViewStyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown</item>
</style>
```

In my case, `dropDownListViewStyle` by default is `@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown`, which is inherited from `android:Widget.ListView` :

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ListView" parent="android:Widget.ListView">
    <item name="android:listSelector">?attr/listChoiceBackgroundIndicator</item>
</style>
```

So just not to mess up other settings, I decided to use `android:Widget.ListView` as the parent and change the property of `android:listSelector`.