# Disable ripple effect on Spinner dropdown item Android

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

I have Spinner with custom layout for its dropdown view using CheckedTextView. The checkedtextview have custom background to use custom color and corner radius. But the ripple effect kinda ruin its UI. How to disable the ripple?

I have tried using set `rippleColor`, `itemRippleColor` and `foreground` to null or transparent, but it doesnt work. Here is my code

Spinner:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                    android:id="@+id/spnSelectYear"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:entries="@array/array_year" />
```

Spinner theme:

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_spinner</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/bg_rounded_white</item>
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment">textStart</item>
</style>
```

Item Dropdown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/tvYear"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/dimen_10dp"
    android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/dimen_4dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_background_dropdown"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
    tools:text="Select" />
```

[image]

Comment: Please Refer to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28005053) I hope your problem is slove

Comment: that does not work @jcredking and AFAIK that is for enabling it, not disable it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the default attributes for spinner list view style.

Modify your "themes.xml" file like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <!-- existing codes. -->

    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/SpinnerListStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerListStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```