# Change the TEXT (not background) color of a spinner when an item is selected

Tags: android

I have a spinner with several options, each displaying a simple string. Initially, the text is all white. However, if the user selects an option (causing it to become what is displayed on top), I would like that text to become red.

How can I do this?

**EDIT : solved**

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
   ((TextView) arg1).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E3170D"));
}
```

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584158/setting-background-color-for-spinner-item-on-selection

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> if the user selects an option (causing it to become what is displayed
>   on top), I would like that text to become red.

So you most likely created OnItemSelectedListener() for your Spinner. So in onItemSelected() method you can simply change text color.

**Pseudocode:**

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
   TextView selectedText = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(0);
   if (selectedText != null) {
      selectedText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
   }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this definitely works, I actually figured it out a few mutes ago but hadn't posted it yet. One minor modification though, see my edit if youre curious

Comment: This doesn't work right when you rotate it though.  See my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33747884/android-nullpointerexception-spinner-onitemselected-view-parameter-is-null-a

Answer (score 2):

see this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584158/setting-background-color-for-spinner-item-on-selection) and i will copy and paste it

1. Create custom View layout (e.g. from TextView)
2. Create Selector and set it as a background of that view
3. Set Spinner with custom view

Selector: custom_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@color/light_grey" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/light_grey" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@color/light_grey" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/light_grey"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</selector>
```

Custom View layout: my_simple_item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:lines="1"
android:padding="5dip"
android:background="@drawable/custom_selector"/>
```

Initialise Spinner:

```
String[] items = new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_simple_item, items);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm a little confused. I create the "selector" (the item on top), in the styles xml, right? Then where do I apply that style to the my_simple_item?

Comment: I think this will change background of textview but not textcolor

Comment: on your spinner, just use this line `android:background="@drwable/custom_selector"`

Comment: also your custom_selector has to be in the drawable folder

Comment: now please try it your self and if the results was n't as you expected then a lettel change in the code will make it work, now just tell me if you can set a background to the spinner

Comment: @WilliamKinaan: I tweaked this code (`android:textcolor` instead of `android:background`), and it worked in changing the color of the text while the spinner is down, but what I wanted was to change the color of the top item when one is selected. Hence the answer posted above.. Thanks for the help though, +1

Answer (score 2):

some of you that using `MaterialBetterSpinner` and Binding your Layouts, 
 all the above won't help, try this, hope it helps you:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {      

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);           

    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final YourXMLBinding rowBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.yourXML, parent,false);
        rowBinding.tv1.setText(mMy.getValues().get(position));
        if(position == mMy.getCurrentIndex()) {
            rowBinding.tv1.setTypeface(Typer.set(getContext()).getFont(Font.ROBOTO_BOLD));//change font
            rowBinding.tv1.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.yourColor));//change color
        }
        return rowBinding.getRoot();
    }
}
```

yourXML is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundStart">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

</layout>
```

create a spinner with this adapter and yourXML :

```
final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.yourXML, s.getValues());

final MaterialBetterSpinner spinner = new MaterialBetterSpinner(getContext());
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this to change the text of selected Text

```
YOUR_SPINNER.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
         TextView selectedText=  view.findViewById(R.id.text_view_name_in_Adapter);
         selectedText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.YOUR_COLOR));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/red" />
 <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
  </selector>
```

and in your activity xml:

```
 <Spinner...............
 android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
  android:background="@drawable/sample"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `OnItemSelectedListener` to your spinner.

```
qtySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.BLACK); //Change selected text color
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```