# Flip arrow on android spinner in toolbar

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner in a toolbar at the bottom of the screen, but the arrow next to the spinner points down, which is counterintuitive. Is there any quick way to flip the arrow to point upwards instead?

[image]

If it helps, the spinner is defined as follows:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_floors"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And the row layout is just `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item`.

On another note, is there any way to change the font color to white without affecting the font color when the spinner is expanded?

### Update

I managed to switch the color of the text using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564760/change-the-text-not-background-color-of-a-spinner-when-an-item-is-selected). I also switched the background for [this image](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_arrow_drop_up) so that now the code is

```
<Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner_floors"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_white_24dp" />
```

Now it looks like this:

[image]

**How do I move the button to the right?**

Note: I'm using Android Marshmallow, API level 23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default background of a spinner is a [9-patch drawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch), so it can scale accordingly. If you want to invert the arrow you have to copy the drawable and invert it manually.

Here I took the background of the spinner found on Lollipop<sup>1</sup> and flipped it vertically:

> [image: flipped spinner background]

You can copy that and save it into the `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder as a 9-patch, i.e. with the extension `.9.png` (not just `.png`).

<sup>1</sup> `[android-sdk]/platforms/android-22/data/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/spinner_mtrl_am_alpha.9.png`

---

Since Marshmallow, the default background is an XML drawable (selector and vector drawable). If you only want to support Android 6.0 and newer you can copy that from the Ansroid SDK and modify it such that it is vertically flipped.

You can find the drawable in the *[android-sdk]/platforms/android-23/data/res/drawable/* directory. It's named `spinner_background_material.xml` and depends on `control_background_40dp_material.xml` and `ic_spinner_caret.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_floors"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown" <!-- You can use your own drawable -->
     />
```

Comment: I switched out the background for [this image](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_arrow_drop_up) but the arrow isn't in the right place, it looks like [this](http://imgur.com/44QAyZv)

Answer (score 3):

Use this with your own icon for example: https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_arrow_drop_up

**toolbar_spinner.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_spinner"
        style="@style/Widget.MyApp.HeaderBar.Spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar_spinner_item_actionbar.xml:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**toolbar_spinner_item_dropdown.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#ff333333"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And add this to your `Styles`:

```
<style name="Widget.MyApp.HeaderBar.Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">?android:selectableItemBackground</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@null</item>
        <item name="android:overlapAnchor">true</item>
</style>
```

Then add it in the `OnCreate`:

```
Toolbar toolbar = getActionBarToolbar();

View spinnerContainer = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.toolbar_spinner,
        toolbar, false);
ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
toolbar.addView(spinnerContainer, lp);

YourObjectSpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter = new YourObjectSpinnerAdapter();
spinnerAdapter.addItems(getMyObjectSpinnerData());

Spinner spinner = (Spinner) spinnerContainer.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
```

**Taken from:** https://dabx.io/2015/01/02/material-design-spinner-toolbar-style-fix/

With some changes and updating.

---

And here is the another method with changing the icon, thanks to Floern for suggest:

You have to create two `drawable` file named:

1.`control_background_40dp_material.xml`

2.`spinner_background_material.xml`

And, **the first one content:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:radius="20dp" />
```

**Second one:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingMode="stack"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingStart="0dp">
    <item
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/control_background_40dp_material"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical" />

    <item
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_up_black_24dp"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical" />
</layer-list>
```

That's it, just use that `Spinner` like this:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_floors"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_background_material"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

There you go, have fun.