# how to add a small triangle in spinner?

Tags: android

I implemented my own custom Adapter spinner as you can see in the code.
everything is working except that that the image is attached from the left side on each value instead attached only to the selected value.
in the following image this is what i get:
[image]

and this is my code:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private String[] values;

    public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int txtViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(ctx, txtViewResourceId, objects);
        context = ctx;
        values = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
        return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
        return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt);
    }
    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent,
                false);
        TextView subSpinner = (TextView) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.sub_text_seen);
        subSpinner.setText(values[position]);
        ImageView right_icon = (ImageView) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.left_pic);


        return mySpinner;
    }
}
```

this is the initalize of the adapter:

```
spinnerduration.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, weeks_array));
    spinnerduration.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /*TextView selectedText = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(0);
            if (selectedText != null) {
                selectedText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }*/
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            /*TextView selectedText = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(0);
            if (selectedText != null) {
                selectedText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            }*/
        }
    });
```

Comment: set `Spinner` background image

Comment: what do you mean? instead using the image just set background for the spinner?

Comment: should i delete the ImageView object? and set the background in the clickListener?

Comment: You must use two different views for  `getDropDownView` and for `getView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate visible items and if they are not selected you should erase image:

```
selectedItem.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

if it's selected you need to set your triangle drawable:

```
selectedItem.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: where should i use it? in the onSelectedItemListener?

Comment: How do you use adapter? Probably, you set spinner adapter with an instance of your adapter class. There you can also set it's background.

Comment: yes exactly i create a new instance from MyAdapter. should i set the background after i set the adapter?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean and edited my answer.

Comment: can you look at my code? i edited him and still i dont understand how to use the "selectedItem" object.

Comment: take a look at the following sample: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7584311/1099716. Do you want to highlight selected item in spinner?